# What Boss’ Weakness is their Pancreas?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

In *Plants vs. Zombies*, Crazy Dave says that he knows the Zomboss’ weakness and says to hit him in the pancreas, but then he says *no, that was a different guy*.

What guy/boss is Dave alluding to?

I highly doubt that he was just making a joke, saying something stupid, or being crazy because right after that, he says *Press Left, Left, Right, Right, Up, Down… oh wait, that’s not it either*.

This is clearly not just a stupid comment or joke, it’s a definitive allusion to the Konami code.

Comment: It's possible Crazy Dave wasn't alluding to anyone; after all, he *is* ***crazy***.

Comment: I bet its some sort of obscure movie reference

Comment: [Ow, my pancreas!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUhaqBBKHOs)

Comment: Kevin, not likely, check the update. William, I’m fairly sure it’s a game reference, check the update. jwaddell, wth *was* that‽

Comment: @Syne The first part is just a generic reference to the fact that bosses often have an obscure weak spot.  The fact that the second part is a reference to a specific thing doesn't mean that the first part has to be also.

Comment: Except that the second item (the Konomi code) was also meant as his trying to recall what the Zomboss’ weakness is. After that, he mutters, then finally remembers what the weakness is before getting hoisted into the air by a bungee zombie. That whole sequence was meant as an amusing intro to the Zomboss with witty references for the astute to enjoy (eg easter eggs).

Comment: Just because the second line is a reference doesn't mean the first is.

Comment: I still don’t think it is just a random comment, but I suppose I can (learn to accept) it (in reference to *The fact that the second part is a reference to a specific thing doesn't mean that the first part has to be also.* and *Just because the second line is a reference doesn't mean the first is.*)

Comment: …of course that would mean that the game devs wrote inconsistent dialog which seems kind of insulting. ¬_¬

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can tell, there are no bosses with a 'weakness in the pancreas'. Given that hitting someone in the pancreas would be a really stupid way to describe hitting someone in the stomach/kidneys anyway:

[image: Pancreas]

I reckon this is just a stupid comment and nothing more.

Comment: *> I reckon this is just a stupid comment and nothing more.* Not likely, check the update.

Comment: Either my google-fu is very weak, or there is no bad guy who succumbs to a pancreas hit. Just because the second line is a reference doesn't mean the first is.